# Oracle Query fetching table name alongwith column name

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select trx_id,refernce number from
(select * from abcd_1_txt union
select * from abcd_2_txt union
select * from abcd_3_txt union
select * from abcd_4_txt)
where trx_id in (123,321,1234)
```

In the query all the tables are of same format, same column names and same number of columns.
After running this query, surely i will get some data.
My question --- is there any way to know from which of these tables, i am getting the output.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add a column with number of query as below

```
select qrynum, trx_id,refernce number from
(select 1 as qrynum,* from abcd_1_txt union
select 2,* from abcd_2_txt union
select 3,* from abcd_3_txt union
select 4,* from abcd_4_txt)
where trx_id in (123,321,1234)
```

as [Joe W](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202843/joe-w) said in the comment below you can also use name of the table instead of query number, short example:

```
select tabname, trx_id,refernce number from
(select 'abcd_1_txt' as tabname,* from abcd_1_txt union
...
where trx_id in (123,321,1234)
```

but both ways don't eliminate duplicates, so you can use `union all` instead of `union`. Other way to do that is to run quires separately with the condition

```
 select * from abcd_1_txt where trx_id in (123,321,1234)
 select * from abcd_2_txt where trx_id in (123,321,1234)
  .
  .
  .
```

Comment: You can also use the table names or some similar text which would eliminate the need to remember the order of the query.

Comment: @JoeW Thank you for the comment, I've added your suggestion to my answer.